# How do you use ENV variables in CMD, on an Alpine based image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've tried a few different ways to get the `WORKERS` variable in the the `CMD` statement, but none of them seem to work. Alpine-based containers also seem very picky on syntax and usage in general. Any help would be appreciated.

**Dockerfile**

```
ENV WORKERS=2

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "-b 0.0.0.0:5000", "-w ${WORKERS}", "app:app"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Alpine doesn't run the application from a sub-shell, following this pattern will allow it to work correctly.

```
ENV WORKERS=2
ENV WORKER_TIMEOUT=60

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn \
     -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w ${WORKERS} -t ${WORKER_TIMEOUT} app:app"]
```

Comment: This is default docker behaviour and should not be related to alpine.

Comment: I've never had to explicitly use `/bin/sh -c` before the command, but I usually do Debian based images.

Comment: @atamanroman is correct. If you use the string form of `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` you don't need to add the shell because docker does that automatically. Since you're using the json array form you had to add `sh` yourself. This has nothing to do with alpine.

Comment: @nephin but then the environment variable won't evaluate.